# SF Android App , not loading scripts in iframe

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

We have created an application which has an iframe that displays contents in Sales force, we are making callout to external system and we have written some Scripts , application is working fine for IOS, Classic and Lightning but when we try to open it in Android we are facing weird issue which we are not able to figure out, We tried to debug using Charles, and got some logs but unable to get the issue from those.
Sharing an error message
`Stream 1 reset with error code 8`  , I know I have not added much details but to be honest that's the only error message I could figure out from logs that we have.

or any other idea how we can debug the issue to figure out why our app is failing when opend in Android.